# Netty on Android - InvalidKeyException

Tags: android, netty

I'm trying to run netty on android. It works fine on Motorola Xoom tablet running 3.2. But it constantly fails on Samsung Galaxy S and Galaxy Tab running 2.3.6 and 3.1 respectively. The exception trace is as below. Has someone faced this earlier.. Any workaround on this.. thanks.

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: The public key in the 
certificate cannot be used for ENCRYPT_MODE 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:815) 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:747) 
     at 
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientHandshakeImpl.processServerHelloDone(ClientHandshakeImpl.java: 
418)
```

Answer (score 2):

This has symptoms consistent with the bug in earlier versions of Android's implementation of `Cypher` where if other party's certificate has KeyUsage extension flag set to Critical and at the same time does not include KeyUsage "DataEncipherment" then Android's implementation of `Cipher` thinks the certificate is not valid and throws Exception which apparently is not the correct behavior.

I found a work around here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9307#c180 but then I improved on it and posted back: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9307#c184 . This got my code working on Android 2.2. Do not be put off by seemingly irrelevant topic where this link points to.

Comment: The link to the workaround was really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Your approach works for Android 4.0/4.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be fixed in 3.0 or later: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12955

Based on the line numbers you gave, you have the old version of javax/crypto/Cipher.java. [This patch](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12955#c12) should fix it.

Edit:
If that doesn't fix it, the [SSL Engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) likely doesn't have a cipher suite enabled that is compatible with your server. You can use [openssl s_client connect](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) or [the script given here](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/is-there-a-tool-that-can-test-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-of) to see what ciphers your server likes and enable those.